# email after IDLE exits out of code Restart

Tags: python, email, restart, python-idle

I've tried to find some help with online searches and wasn't able to find anything so I'm posting on here and hoping.  I've got a bunch of code with 3 "for" loops and a try/except statement inside of the 3rd "for" loop.  I run the module from IDLE and it runs fine for about 16 hours then just quits and prints on the IDLE command screen =====Restart====.  It does this randomly so I can't replicate it but I've gone through by hand and was able to process the data that it quit on without a problem.  Does anyone know of a way to have python email myself when this occurs?  I've tried putting the main code inside of a definition and use a
try:
    definition
except:
    send email

but this doesn't work either.  I've got the emailing part of the code working fine.  I apologize that I am not including the code here.  I've talked to my boss about it, but since it is dealing with sensitive data I'm not allowed to.  Any guidance that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you running the module from IDLE instead of just from the command line?

Comment: Well, since the behavior you're seeing exists in IDLE, the first, most obvious troubleshooting step is to take IDLE out of the equation. That way you'll know whether it's an IDLE bug or a bug in your code.

Comment: Per your suggestion I'm started running it in the command window.  After 115 times through the loops, the python command window just closed.  I'm fine with it if it dies, but some notification of when it does quit would be helpful so I can restart the program where it left off.

Comment: Then there's a bug in the code. Post the traceback and someone might be able to help. (You'll have to start it from an existing command window to get this information.)